# Scala Future `.onComplete` function discarded after call?

Tags: scala, concurrent.futures

Are the function bodies passed to `Future.onComplete()`, and their closures, discarded and so garbage collected after they are called?

I ask because I'm writing an unbounded sequence of `Future` instances. Each `Future` has an `.onComplete { case Failure(t)...}` that refers to the previous known-good value from a previous `Future`. What I want to avoid is the total history of all `Future` results being kept in the JVM's memory because of references in closure bodies.

Perhaps Scala is more clever than this, but skimming the code related to execution contexts and futures isn't yielding much.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class that normally implements `Future` and that you want to look at is `DefaultPromise`.

It contains mutable state that is being updated as the Future completes.

- If you call `onComplete` and it has already been completed then it just schedules your callback immediately with the result. The callback is not recorded anywhere.
- If you call `onComplete` while the result is not yet available, the callback is added to a list of "listeners".
- When the result becomes available (someone calls `complete` on the promise), then all listeners are scheduled to run with that result, and the list of listeners is deleted (the internal state changes to "completed with this result")

This means that your callback chain is only being built up until the "upstream future" is incomplete. After that, everything gets resolved and garbage-collected.

---

"list of listeners" above is a bit of a simplification. There is special care being taken that these listeners do not end up referring to each-other, specifically to break reference loops that would prevent garbage collection to work when constructing futures recursively. Apparently this was indeed a problem in earlier versions.

> The problem of leaks is solved by automatically breaking these chains of promises, so that promises don't refer to each other in a long chain. This
>     allows each promise to be individually collected. The idea is to "flatten"
>       the chain of promises, so that instead of each promise pointing to its
>       neighbour, they instead point directly the promise at the root of the
>       chain. This means that only the root promise is referenced, and all the
>       other promises are available for garbage collection as soon as they're no
>      longer referenced by user code.